# Azure AD B2C Email Invitation - Social Accounts Only

Tags: xml, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement an invitation sign-up process for Azure AD B2C using custom policies.

These are the policies I'm using for reference: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite-via-email

The policies in the repository above use local accounts for the example, but my B2C tenant is only validating users with outside IDPs. I am not using local accounts at all.

I keep getting this error while trying to adjust the RedeemInvite.xml policy to social accounts.

> Claim type "alternativeSecurityId" is the input claim of technical profile "AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" in step "3" of user journey "SignInWithIdTokenHint" but it is not an output claim in any of the previous steps.

I'm just changing where the policies from GitHub reference "local accounts" to the same references I have in my base policy for "social accounts,' but I have no idea what that error means. I put a reference to "alternativeSecurityId" under every  in the policy to see if I could find the error.

Claims Provider where alternativeSecurityId is declared as an input.

```
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" PartnerClaimType="alternativeSecurityId" Required="true" />
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
    <!-- Required claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <!-- Optional claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayame" /
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" />
</OutputClaims>
```

User Journey Steps 1-3.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="GetClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims" />
<!-- Check if user tries to run the policy without invitation -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
         <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>email</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
         </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>        
    <ClaimsExchanges>
         <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Unsolicited" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Unsolicited" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<!-- Read the user properties from the directory - should not exist -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
         <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are outputting a claim that doesn't exist.

If you look in the base XML file for the Facebook example:

```
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
```

you see you create an alternativeSecurityId as part of the federation.

So you need to do something similar.